# Haskell - Function 'length' doesn't work with custom data type

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I need to define this data type:

```
data Restaurant = Restaurant [(String, String, Int)] deriving (Eq,Show)
```

that is a list of the employees of the restaurant: (name , address, wage) for each employee.

Now, I'm trying to define this **numberOfEmployees** function:

```
numberOfEmployees :: Restaurant -> Int
numberOfEmployees rest = length rest
```

But I get this compile error: 
Couldn't match expected type ‘t2 a0’ with actual type ‘Restaurant'

Why is it working if I use **type** instead of **data**? (I can't use the 'type' declaration in my code because it's part of an exercise about 'data')

```
type Restaurant = [(String, String, Int)]
```

Comment: Side note: every time you say "I can't do that", you should state a reason here.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is it working if I use type instead of data?

Because `type` is a weak alias. In code, it is equivalent to the type on RHS.

`data` (and `newtype`, perhaps even more so), on the other hand, creates a "strong" alias, which means you need to unpack it first:

```
numberOfEmployees :: Restaurant -> Int
numberOfEmployees (Restaurant rest) = length rest
```

This is especially important if you want to restrict the operations on your data. If your inner module doesn't export the constructor, the user can only use your smart constructors and other operators, and is *unable* to access or modify the wrapped data directly (effectively making it opaque).

Comment: Thank you man! I thought in that case the compiler could infer the type 'inside' my data.

Comment: It technically could, but intentionally doesn't. `data` implies that the User will manually specify al behavior.

Comment: And to add to that, I'm pretty sure you can `derive Foldable` on that.

Answer (score 1):

The function `length` has type `[a] -> Int`. That is it expects a list as an argument. But you are trying to pass a `Restaurant` to it.

You should use pattern matching to get the list and pass that to `length` instead.

```
numberOfEmployees :: Restaurant -> Int
numberOfEmployees (Restaurant a) = length a
```

Comment: That isn't its type any more, and if it were, the error message would be different.

Comment: `length` now has type `Foldable f => f a -> Int`.

Comment: @dfeuer Nevertheless, the proposition "length has the type [a] -> Int" remains true. To verify, compile `myLength :: [a] -> Int; myLength = length`

Comment: @Ingo, that's true. However, a critical part of learning Haskell is getting the hang of interpreting type errors. The type error the OP gets makes no sense under the assumption that `length :: [a] -> Int`.

Comment: @dfeuer ... I guess this was one reason for opposing the FTP proposal for some.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `length` is

```
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

But there are no types `t` and `a` such that the `Restaurant` type equals `t a`. As others have explained, you'll need to pull out the list and find the length of the list—a `Restaurant` can never have a `length`.

#### Nitpick

You could write

```
type Foo a = Restaurant
```

So that

```
Foo a ~ Restaurant
```

for each `a`. However, `Foo` will only be a type synonym/family and not a proper first-class type. Only bona fide types declared with `data` or `newtype`, the built-in `()`, list, and tuple types, the oddball `->`, and applications of these, really count.